# Can I influence my Steam region?

Tags: steam

There's an Unreal pack available on Steam – but not in my region (Germany) probably due to Germany's laws against graphical violence for minors. I had the idea to ask a friend in the USA to register an account for me, buy the game, then give me the password and I log in from my home.

Will I be able to download games which have previously been bought with my account even if they're not offered for sale in the region that I'm currently in?

(Might be a real disappointment to real Americans who come to Germany for a longer period ...)

Comment: Duplicate of [Left For Dead 2 - Unlock Australian Censorship](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/left-for-dead-2-unlock-australian-censorship). See [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/left-for-dead-2-unlock-australian-censorship/12040#12040) answer.

Comment: Thanks, good to know this. But this is still not a duplicate because my whole intent is to buy the game in a foreign version in the first place, not hack an existing version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your intent may be different, but I'll give you the same answer as on the suspected duplicate:

Ask your friend to buy the game for you and give it to you as a gift. (If he doesn't have an account yet, he should register with *his* actual location and, most importantly, *his* credit card/Paypal account.)

That has always worked for me so far, although I haven't tried with Unreal in particular.

Comment: This does not seem to work any longer. I asked a friend from USA to buy and gift me a game, but its still the "Low violence version".

Answer (score 9):

Valve can (and has) locked out games attached to peoples Steam accounts that are from a different region than the one they live in.

This was a [big deal](http://consumerist.com/2007/10/valve-deactivating-customers-who-bought-orange-box-internationally.html) with the Orange Box first launched.

Comment: link returns 404 :/