# (How) Is it possible to get the full version of a game if I can only buy its low violence version?

Tags: steam

While I don't exactly *loathe* the censorship called "low violence version" for some games steam sells (e.g. [Fallout 3](http://store.steampowered.com/app/22370/))

[image: German low violence version only available with German language]

I *do* detest being forced to play games in a language different than the original one, which is usually English - especially since I often experience terrible mistranslations and not-so-great German speakers.

[Portal](http://store.steampowered.com/app/400/), like most Valve games, I think, allows to set the language via properties -> language.

However, I recently bought [Bioshock](http://store.steampowered.com/app/7670/) misreading the "only" in that shop message as "the German version is censored" and not as "this version *is* German only" since I don't have any language option. I already set Steam itself to English on installation, but to no avail.

> Is it possible to play games in a language not made available via Steam?

Obviously I'm asking for legal ways and don't want to accidentally get a ban instead of a better speech...

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this message have been any less ambiguous had you used Steam in German? "Gewaltgeminderte Version - nur auf Deutsch verfügbar"

Comment: uhm, ye-es.... :-( But let's just say there is a good reason I set Steam to English. Just as you are glad setting Steam to Italian didn't change the speech ;-)

Comment: I'm happy because I can use the Italian version of Steam and [help improve it](https://translation.steampowered.com) without having to hear low-budget dubs ;)

Comment: @badp good point

Comment: Maybe this doesn't help but: personally, if any game that I'd legitimately bought had some annoying problem with it, I think I'd simply pirate a working version of it without any concern for whether that was technically legal or not. Can't see how you can get a ban doing that (though multiplayer games are different, I guess).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem of region restriction and low violence content has already been discussed [**here**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/can-i-influence-my-steam-region/13139#13139). Basically those restrictions are applied based on who *purchases* the game, not who *plays* it. You need somebody in a non restricted area to gift that game to you. Alternatively, you could spend your holidays in one such country and purchase the game from there with a local payment method (apparently you can buy prepaid cards from gas stations, or at least that's what Redditors say to people who have no credit card; YMMV).

Comment: Your answer may help others who don't know about that option, but as mentioned in my case it's a region lock issue. I'm not exactly asking how to change my region, although the answers to that question might be valid here too. I guess it's up to you to decide whether it's duplication or correlation

Comment: @Tobias I'll go with correlation then.

Comment: wait, even though now I registered as living in Germany, I still can purchase foreign version when I'm not in German internet?

Comment: @Tobias I would say so, but I pinged a German that IIRC has tried exactly that. AFAIK he was successful. Besides, you could make a new account in that country and then gift the game to your main account. That won't change your billing information, however.

Comment: @badp: I think if he already has the game it won't let him switch to the uncensored version.  I haven't tried it myself, but from what my friends have said, it only lets you accept a gift of a game if you don't already have it...

Comment: @Tobias The problem with buying while being on vacation is, as I have painfully noticed, that while you'll be able to put something in your cart there, they'll reject your payment method (I think I tried credit card and Paypal) as not matching your current location. So I couldn't buy anything then, not even something also available in my home country.

Comment: @Cort maybe another € country works. Should I have the opportunity to test this, I'll post the results here

Comment: @Tobias Nope, sorry. I'm living in Germany (and have a German Paypal account and credit card) and tried from the Netherlands.

Comment: @Cort: Thanks :( So the only choices remaining are asking someone from a different country to gift-buy it for you or [importing](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26048). Or finally getting that Swiss number account :-7

Comment: Now that I live in Switzerland, I could finally ask Steam support to remove the German version from my account and re-buy the international edition. Still a sad thing, this geocism...

Comment: @Zommuter Did it work?

Comment: @badp Absolutely. No problem using my still German paypal account, it is indeed the geolocation that causes all that nuisance. Finally I can play BioShock (and other games) in the original language.

Answer (score 5):

I got the uncensored version of Left 4 Dead 2, by buying a non german key.

When I entered the key I was in Germany and it still activated the uncensored version.

You should search for a seller of those keys. The one I bought my keys from went unfortunately out of business.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically it might be possible to copy the language data files from someone else and turning the updating function of, but this would be a last resort and I doubt Valve tolerates that - if it's not actually illegal to obtain a different language version that is not made available.

Answer (score 1):

There are some online shops that import the UK and US versions of games which are uncut. This is perfectly legal, but it comes with some annoying restrictions. They are not allowed to openly advertise certain games and they need to verify that you are over 18 and that nobody under 18 can get their hands onto the game when they send it.

This means you are usually required to send them a copy of your ID (Personalausweis) and you have to receive the package personally, they won't give it to someone else. This costs a bit more money which you can at some shops avoid by sending to a Packstation (where only you can access the package).

I have done this for Fallout 3 at [OkaySoft](http://www.okaysoft.de/pc.htm), there are a few more shops that import games, but I haven't tried it since then. Fortunately most games I bought recently came with the english language also available.

Comment: thanks for the link, this is still cheaper than "having to" go on vacation ;) I'll try this next time, though unfortunately it seems I won't be able to switch bioshock to English then since I already bought it in German...

Answer (score 0):

That's not legally possible. This has nothing to do with Steam itself, but with the laws in Germany.

Since only Germany requires such censorship, only the German versions of games are available to you, unless you get someone else to buy you the game from a non-German country.

Comment: *sigh* :-( yes, but as mentioned I basically don't _need_ to see fountains of blood, yet I'd like to stop my ears bleeding - can't I legally hear the English synchronization while playing the babysitter-friendly version? I also fear having someone buy the game from outside of Germany might result in a ban or at least not really being able to play it - I think I read that some folks bought a less expensive version of a game in some other country just to see it removed from their games list again...

Comment: Well, legally, you only own the German copy of the game. You didn't buy the English language packs. This is obviously the distributor's fault, but there's nothing you can do about it without pirating the language packs I suppose.

Comment: ok, badp's link contains a link to [the orange box issue](http://consumerist.com/2007/10/valve-deactivating-customers-who-bought-orange-box-internationally.html) which is what I was referring to

Comment: I thought Valve claims I actually don't even own the copy but only the right to play it which is how they justify not being able to sell Steam games used... Hm, then at least one should be able to buy the English language pack for half a token Euro or something...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler That's all up to the distributor, has naught to do with Steam. I do believe the German version of L4D2 comes with English voice packs, for example.

Comment: so instead of nagging Steam support 2k games is to blame in the case of Bioshock? Funnily enough, Mafia2 _does_ offer setting the language. But ok, that's not censored, so in the end Germany's "authorities" are to blame :-(

Comment: Actually you can sell the non-censored version of games in Germany, it is just a big hassle as they would have to verify the age of the buyer. I bought the imported version of Fallout 3 from a german vendor, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: @Fabian thanks, good to know. you could add this as a new answer