# Is it possible to gift Steam games to a locale in which they are not (yet) offered?

Tags: steam

Is it possible to gift a Steam game to a user who is in a locale where the game is not being offered?

For instance, [this game has a different release date in different countries](http://www.2kgames.com/blog/civilization-v-gods-amp-kings-releases-june-19). Could I get this game on the 1st day of its release by having someone from an "early" country gift it to me?

This question is similar to [(How) Is it possible to get the full version of a game if I can only buy its low violence version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26008/how-is-it-possible-to-get-the-full-version-of-a-game-if-i-can-only-buy-its-low), and indeed I hope there is a similar answer.

Comment: Hm. Just a week ago I would've answered with an unconditional yes, but apparently the situation has recently changed and now I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: Also, release date is completely separate from the version you have. I noticed that when I got the NA version of The Darkness 2 from a Game Grant, I couldn't play it until it was released in the EU region.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**General:**

The one who is getting the present, is always getting the version of the country the buyer lives in.

**Censorship:**

So yes, it is possible to circumvent low violence with trading AND gifting. 
However, a Publisher might have decided to prevent someone from installing the game when the IP is in a country where the game is blocked. So far this is only true for 1 game from Capcom so far, where I know about. The Game was Dead Rising 2 : Off the Record. That one for example is not installable in Germany, even if you get it gifted or traded, but the store gives me a warning if I visit it via cc=us.

[image: Example: Dead Rising 2 Off the Record]

It is also possible to gift it to someone where it is not available in the store at all. For example, I gave Space Marine to a British friend on Steam, because it was not available in his country on Steam store before release and a while after. ( *wave @ Game* )

**Release Date:**

That is still governed where you live at. For example, a friend gifted me Deus Ex HR Preorder. While the game was already out in the US where he lives, I had to wait the 3 extra days to play it.

Comment: Doesn't fully cover the question, though; if a game is not available at all in, say, Australia, can a US user gift it to them? I believe the answer is yes (absent the Capcom game caveat) but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Dead Rising.  Was it 1 or 2?  I worked on the localization tools for DR2 and I'd be saddened if they enforced it with IP checks.  Though of course the real problem is silly laws.

Comment: I have updated the answer, to be more clear on the matter when a game is not available. Since I am german, I use the gift-feature a lot an so far I always got the games uncut and could install them, even if not available. @Matthew Thanks, it was Dead Rising 2. It is the only game on Steam I know where it does not work. But if I visit the games page on steam with cc=us, it warns me about it.

Comment: Excellent and comprehensive answer, thank you! (though I think it's better if you would give the paragraph after the screenshot a header of its own, since it deals with a different scenario)