# Does US Scribblenauts Unlimited activate on a EU Steam account?

Tags: steam, scribblenauts-unlimited

If I buy Scribblenauts Unlimited (PC) at Amazon.com and ship it to Europe, will I be able to attach it to my German Steam account or at least play it at all?

Comment: I think the answer is "yes." See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/13139/23

Comment: (Regional restrictions suck.)

Comment: @badp This is only true for gifting, not if you enter a key. If you enter a key a lot more restrictions apply, while through gifting those do not apply and you can most likely play all games uncut and without restrictions. There are some cases though where gifts from different regions cannot be activated or even installed in Germany such as Dead Rising 2 and in general gifts from Russia.