# Cross region steam gifting?

Tags: steam

My friends live in different regions. Almost none of us are in the same region.

Is there anyway we can gift games to each other?

Humble-bundle and G2A seem like options, but lack the games I want to get. I don't know any other ones yet.

I am not looking for Steam giftcard options.

Comment: Unsure if [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16718/can-i-gift-games-to-people-in-other-areas-of-the-world) answers this or not.  It seems to be about re-gifting to someone in a different region.  It's also quite old.

Comment: Hmm. That's quite a unique case. I wonder if I can not reply to the gift, then gift it from that inventory, or original inventory. Assuming this still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if the price difference is less than 10%. This was changed [last year](https://gamerant.com/steam-gifting-games-problem/) due to people abusing the then pricing of games in Turkey and Argentina.

If this is not an option, you would need to get a key compatible with their region. You can get them from official resellers like Humble Bundle, Fanatical and GMG (you can check the [r/gamedeals list](https://rgamedeals.net) for more sites). Avoid Gray/Black market sites like G2A and Kinguin.

As a last resort, you can buy Steam Gift Cards in their currency.