# Left 4 Dead 2 - purchase non low violence version?

Tags: steam, left-4-dead-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left For Dead 2 - Unlock Australian Censorship](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/left-for-dead-2-unlock-australian-censorship)

I hopped onto Steam to buy Left 4 Dead 2, and I saw this banner:

[image: Low Violence: Low Violence Version]

This seems a bit un-cool to me, but I couldn't find any way to purchase a non-low-violence version.

Is it possible?

Comment: Though the German LV-version contains much cooler Counter Strike: Source weapons as a bonus :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably because of the country you are buying from. I believe someone can gift you the regular version if they buy it in a country that allows it.

Alternatively, you can buy the low violence version and use the instructions found here to enable the gore:

http://www.destructoid.com/blogs/Skribble/left4dead2-australian-gore-fix--153748.phtml

Comment: Hmm, that'll do nicely. I don't know anyone overseas, so I'll try the instructions on that page.

Comment: I can confirm that _yes_ it works to have someone in an uncensored region buy it for you. The version of the game you get depends on the _buyer_, not the _player_: if a North American buys you L4D2, you get the North American L4D2 no matter where you live.